# What causes a library not found error in gcc, when the library exists?

Tags: linux, gcc, boost, compiler-errors

After a reformat/reinstall of Linux, I'm trying to build some code that used to work. I'm not sure how to debug this sort of error. While I'd like to know what's wrong with this code below, I'd like to also know how to track down the problem -- what are the clues to look for?

```
$ more test.c

void main() {}

$ gcc test.c
<works>

$ gcc test.c -lboost_system
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

$ gcc test.c -lboost_filesystem
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

$ locate boost_filesystem
/usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0

$ locate boost_system
/usr/lib64/libboost_system.so.1.58.0

$ uname -a
Linux mycomputer 4.2.6-301.fc23.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 22:22:41 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo dnf list installed | grep boost
boost-date-time.x86_64                 1.58.0-9.fc23            @updates        
boost-filesystem.x86_64                1.58.0-9.fc23            @updates        
boost-iostreams.x86_64                 1.58.0-9.fc23            @updates        
boost-system.x86_64                    1.58.0-9.fc23            @updates        
boost-thread.x86_64                    1.58.0-9.fc23            @updates
```

**UPDATE**
@Kenny suggested I look for the devel package.  It wasn't installed. `dnf install boost-devel` and it got installed.  Then, when I run `gcc test.c -lboost_system`, it works.  However, I'm still at a loss.  What mechanism/file/setting got changed to make this work?  When I run `locate boost_system`, I still come up with the same.  I realize that package installed some header files, but my test.c didn't mention boost in it.

Comment: Have you installed `libboost-filesystem-dev` aswell?

Comment: That was it -- I had to install boost-devel.  Other than trying to remember if the *devel packages are installed, what did I miss?  After installing, when I run locate, I still come up with the same.  There is no actual mention of boost in that `test.c` I showed.  What got installed that made this work? (It be just all headers that fixed this -- what was it?)

Comment: There are `.a` library archive files that are used during linking. You might be able list the contents of the -devel package and you'd see something like `/usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0.a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Debian and Debian-derived distros, such as Ubuntu, library packages are usually divided in the *binary package* and the *development package*.

The library binary package will usually have the shared library file, with its full, three-digit-version name (`libfoo.so.1.2.3`) and a symlink to it with the one and/or two-digit-version name (`libfoo.so.1.2`, `libfoo.so.1`) pointing to the first one. This one-or-two-digit-version file is what it is actually looked for when running a program (google for `ELF SONAME` for details).

The library development package will usually contain the header files (`*.h`) and a symlink without any version numbers to the shared object (`libfoo.so`). Optionally, there may be also a static library file (`libfoo.a`).

Now, when you compile a program and you add the `-lfoo` option, the linker will look for a file `libfoo.so` that is actually a symlink to `libfoo.so.1.2.3` and it will use that file as a shared library.

And that's why this symlink is in the dev package and not the bin one: since the shared library has a SONAME with `libfoo.so.1` or `libfoo.so.1.2` the runtime program does not need the `libfoo.so` symlink. It's only used for building.

PS: to see the files in a package do not use `locate`. Use `dpkg -L libboost-filesystem-dev`.